# Papa parse cannot parse string but can parse that same string printed to the console

Tags: javascript, import-from-csv, papaparse

I am running into an extremely stupid and infuriating issue.

I am getting a string from my server which I try to parse with Papa.parse to no avail.

If I print this string to the console by calling it and then copy/pasting that string into Papa.parse, it does work.

Code :

```js
// this does not work
Papa.parse(res.result, {header: true, skipEmptyLines: true});
```

You can see that the `\n` in the string are not interpreted as linebreak so Papa thinks all values are fields.

[image]

`res.result`

[image]

```js
//copy-paste the string printed in the console
a = "the_string_I_just_copied"
```

[image]

```js
Papa.parse(a)
```

[image]

Seems like something happens when I print it in the console because the line return characters are interpreted as line returns but I don't know what to do with that information.

Comment: "to no avail" and "this does not work" is hardly descriptive enough to guide you with this question.  Do you have any errors thrown in console?  Can you re-create the issue in a code snippet as a [mcve]?  screenshots are terribly difficult to debug.

Comment: it's because I can't reproduce it in a fiddle that I had to do the console thingy... There are no errors, only Papa does not recognize my initial string as parsable.

Comment: added a comment in the question to point to `\n` not being recognized as line break initially.

Comment: If `\n` is readable as is in the log of `res.result` it means that `res.result` does contain the sequence `\\n`. PapaParse did it's job correctly here, the first \  will make the sequence get ignored.

Comment: so should I change my newline character on the server side to something else ?

Comment: Well why is it this way in the first place? If it's csv data then yes, it's expected that new-lines are rows delimiters, so if your server side got rid of these all, it simply broke your csv data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`res.result` contains the sequence `\\n`, otherwise your log wouldn't print `\n` as readable characters, but really just as a new line:

```js
console.log( "hello\nworld" );
console.log( "hello\\nworld" );
```

This sequence **doesn't** represent the new line character, and thus it's only normal your parser doesn't recognize it as a row delimiter.

You need to fix your data.

Comment: I ended up replacing the new line character server side by something unambiguous (`|` in that case)